# Printing a Sentence in C word by word, without using string.h

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm currently learning how to program in C. As extra practice I was given some problems from my teacher. 
Here is what my problem is, I have to use this in my program:

```
 void strSplitTokens (char *s1, char s2[][], int *numWords);
```

here is the rest of the problem: *A call to strSplitTokens breaks string s1 into its words, it then saves each word in a distinct char array, and all the strings are saved in a single array of characters. Also, it saves the number of words using pointers in numWords. print the strings in the main with the following:*

```
For(i=0;i<numWords;i++) printf("%s\n",s2[i]);
```

If I run it and give it a sentence like *I like programming* I need it to output:

I

Like

Programming

My main issue is that I was told not to use string.h, I am kind of lost on how to do it without it.  Any advice and guidance would is greatly appreciated.

What I have so far is mostly mock up code which makes no sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strSplitTokens (char *s1, char s2[][], int *numWords);
int main()
{
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    strSplitTokens();

 For(i=0;i<numWords;i++) 
{
        printf("%s\n",s2[i]);
}
    return 0;
}
void strSplitTokens (char *s1, char s2[][], int *numWords);
{
    char s1;
    scanf("%s",&s1);
    if( s1 != '\n')
    {
        strSplitTokens();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what code you have so far.

Comment: You should probably do like this, traverse the string, when you encounter a alphanumeric character start by putting that character in a temporary array and increment a counter, do this for each char until you find a space, now `malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1))` and copy your word to the new space, do this for each word.

Comment: You are calling strSplitTokens from strSplitTokens (recursion). I'm pretty sure you don't want to be doing this.

Comment: @Gille I have very little in the way of code. I'm struggling on how to write anything while still using the required function.

Comment: @user1855131 no problem, so how do you find a word in the string? I'd search for ' ' (strchr essentially). Then in a loop realloc s2 to fit the extra word and strdup it. If you found '\n' or '\0' before ' ' you're done!

Comment: so something like 
while(*(s1+i)!='\0') i++;
end=s1+i-1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check character by character. Put the each character in the two dimensional array until space comes.

```
i=0;j=0;k=0;  
while(s[k]!='\n') {
    if(s[k]!=' ')
    {
        s1[i][j]=s[k];
        k++; 
        j++;
    }
    else{
        j=0;i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to increment k in the else? Because the way you have it now would make the code loop infinitely when it finds a space if I'm not mistaken.